# Inserting dateTime to mysql

Tags: php, datetime, pdo

I have this code using PHP PDO to insert some data to table in a database. My problem is when i started inserting dateTime. What I am trying to do is when the form is sent, datetime will automatically be set or entered in the dateTimeSent column in my database table named-comments.

In the database table, the dateTimeSent column is structured as DATETIME, with current default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

---

My PHP code has this:

```
if(isset($_POST['senderEmail'])) {
$senderName   = $_POST['senderName'];
$senderEmail  = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$comments     = $_POST['comments'];

$dateTimeSent = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //IS THIS CORRECT AND PROPERLY PLACED???

$q= "INSERT INTO comments(senderName, senderEmail, comments,dateTimeSent) VALUES (:senderName, :senderEmail, :comments, :dateTimeSent,);";
$query    = $dbh  ->prepare($q);
$results  = $query->execute(array(
    ":senderName"=>$senderName,
    ":senderEmail"=>$senderEmail,
    ":comments"=>$comments,
    ":dateTimeSent"=>$dateTimeSent,
));
}
```

I am a newbie, and i don`t know if i am doing the datetime right.

Thanks who will help me enlighten.

Comment: Let me tell you what your question have to be. to insert a datatime in mysql you need a **string**  like `'2011-11-26 01:00:27'`. So your question have to be not on jquery, not on mobile, not on PDO, but on this very string only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for converting

```
date_default_timezone_set('Americas/New_York');
$stamp = strtotime($dateStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am looking for answer how to insert dateTime into mysql database. It doesnt work, so can you point why it is wrong?

Comment: Try removing the comma after the last variable in the VALUES . That might be the problem .